# How to determine if there was no internet access while uploading media to Firebase storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

i have the folliwng code

```
 FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('fo').putData(data).then((value){
      /// done
    }).catchError((error){
      /// error
    });
```

now i want change some in my UI state if there was no Internet , after many tests it seems `FirebaseStorage` never return errors related internet issues

Answer (score 1):

Usually the Firebase SDK only throw these errors [Handle Error Messages](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/handle-errors/#handle-error-messages)

If you want to handle errors with connectivity issues you can use [connectivity](https://pub.dev/documentation/connectivity/latest/) package as follows :

```
class _YourUploadScreenState extends State<YourUploadScreen> {
  final FirebaseStorage _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  final Connectivity _connectivity = Connectivity();

  void uploadData() async {
    var connectivityResult = await _connectivity.checkConnectivity();
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
      // Handle no internet connectivity here
      // Update your UI state accordingly
      return;
    }
    _storage.ref('fo').putData(data).then((value) {
      /// done
    }).catchError((error) {
      /// error
    });
  }
}
```

But if internet connection drops when you are uploading an object then you have to handle such scenarios: [Handle progress and errors with uploadTask](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/upload-files#full-example)

#### Update :

You can also use **[Monitor Upload Progress](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress)** error regarding connectivity errors `TaskState.error` in which docs says :

> Emitted when the upload has failed. This can happen due to network timeouts, authorization failures, or if you cancel the task.

I have tested above method with disconnecting the internet while upload process and I get this error.

The Firebase SDK for Cloud Storage will automatically retry file uploads and resume in the case that the connection is lost and regained. The upload will not just immediately fail when the connection is lost.

Comment: thanks but connectivity plugin will never handle this work perfectly since it return always online if wifi were connected but no access . besides uploadTask also never return any kind of internet issues errors

Comment: @Mohammed Hamdan I have updated my answer based on your query. Can you check ?

Comment: thanks , but are you sure you tested it correctly ? because i do test it , it return the network issues maybe after 15/20 mins after network is disconnected Lol  , i tested it many times